# Default private registry in Docker

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I need to set up my own private registry in Docker, to generally keep *all* internal Docker-images.

To make this easier, I want to have a setup internally where my Docker-images are called `project/component`, just like normal Docker-images you pull from https://index.docker.io/.

I am certain, that I will never grab images in this format from index.docker.io, all those images will come from our internal indexer. Even the images in the format of `imagename`, like `centos` will be pulled from our internal repository.

So, is there a way for me to change out the default indexer? Or at least change my private indexer from port 5000 to something that is tried as default; ie, to grab images from `private_indexer.internal/repo_name` instead of `private_indexer.internal:5000/repo_name`.

Is putting index.docker.io in our own dns pointing to our internal ip the best solution?

Comment: Did spoofing the DNS name work?

Comment: I didn’t try it yet. I'm also wondering what will happened if the hostname of my private repo is `project`, and I do `project/component`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `private_indexer.internal/repo_name` without any issue. Just run registry container on port 80 (you can also add some reverse proxy like nginx or hipache in front and pass traffic from port 80 to 5000).
As for first part of question to change default index url you would probably need to change docker code and recompile. I tried to do this quite few versions ago and it worked but back then there was no easy to use private registry support like now. So IMHO best would be to stick with tagging all private images with private registry url. Then you will not loose access to images in public index (ubuntu, busybox).

Comment: Thanks for the tip! In my opinion; Docker needs to be customizable in this way to really take off at the enterprise. There are few to none of the images on index.docker.io that I care about at work. I will try to spoof the dns-name to see how it goes. Will accept your answer if no-one have the real answer in the meanwhile :)

Comment: I found the place in the sourcecode they took away this feature of having your own standard indexer. The reason is to be predictable. Basicly, if you define `FROM centos`, you will get the same thing, whatever setup you might have. Logical, but slightly annoying as well..

Comment: Also note: Your internal hostname needs to have at least one dot. `my-registry` won't work, `my.registry` will.